# Validating server side with asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database, visual-studio

Currently I have a website with a simple signup form in html, this is the code:

```
<div class="grid_6 push_3 block alpha">

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <label>שם משתמש</label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" pattern="^\S{4,}$" required />
        </div>


        <div class="grid_6 alpha omega  form_block">
            <label>סיסמא</label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" pattern="^\S{6,}$" required title="סיסמא צריכה להכיל לפחות 6 תווים" />
        </div>


        <div class="grid_6 alpha omega  form_block">
            <label>וודא סיסמא</label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <input type="password" id="password2" pattern="^\S{6,}$" required />
        </div>


        <div class="grid_6 alpha omega  form_block">
            <label>כתובת אימייל</label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" />
        </div>


        <div class="grid_6 alpha omega  form_block">
            <label>וודא כתובת אימייל</label>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <input type="email" id="email2" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" />
        </div>

        <div class="grid_6 form_block alpha  omega">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" value="שלח" />
        </div>

    </div>
```

(Its actually being wrapped in  tags from the master page, this is the master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/text.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/963_9_10_10.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<form runat="server">
        <div class="container_9">

            <div class="header grid_9">
                <a href="Default.aspx"><h1>סיכומים.נט</h1></a>
            </div>
            <!-- END HEADER -->

            <nav>
                <ul class="clearfix grid_6 push_3">
                   <a href="literature.aspx"> <li class="grid_1 alpha literature">ספרות</li></a>
                   <a href="language.aspx"> <li class="grid_1 language">לשון</li></a>
                    <a href="civics.aspx"><li class="grid_1 civics">אזרחות</li></a>
                    <a href="history.aspx"><li class="grid_1 history">היסטוריה</li></a>
                   <a href="bible.aspx"> <li class="grid_1 bible">תנך</li></a>
                   <a href="english.aspx"> <li class="grid_1 omega english">אנגלית</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="grid_3 pull_6" id="search">

            <input type="text" id="search_box" placeholder="הקלד מילות חיפוש"/>
            <input type="submit" value="חפש" id="search_button"/>
            </div> 

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            <footer class="grid_9">
              2013 © כל הזכויות שמורות לסיכומים.נט
            </footer>

        </div>
        <!-- END CONTAINER -->
 </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a signup.aspx.cs file that inserts the signup information into the database as follows:

```
public partial class signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form["submit"] != null) {
            register1();
        }

    }

    public void register1()
    {     
      string sql = "INSERT INTO [userinfo] ([username], [password], [email]) VALUES (N'" + Request.Form["username"] + "', N'" + Request.Form["password"] + "', N'" + Request.Form["email"] + "')";
        Database.UpdateData(sql);
    }
}
```

I think i'm doing everything right so far (I'm a beginner in anything beyond html/css) but correct me if I've made any errors.

What I want to do now is validate my form input server-side before I insert it into my database. I want to check that it obeys all my rules, char-lengths, matching fields and so forth - and also that the username/email isn't taken already.

I'm currently doing some basic javascript validation but I understand that isn't sufficient security wise.

an explanation (as simple as possible) as to what I have to go about doing now, would be great. Ideally i would like to return to the signup page and list the errors at the top of the form in a customizable way.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RegularExpressionValidator](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_regularexpvalidator.asp) and [CompareValidator](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_comparevalidator.asp) are going to be your friends here.

For example:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="valEmail" ControlToValidate="email" 
ValidationExpression="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" 
EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="The email is invalid!" 
runat="server" />
```

And:

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="valEmails"
ControlToValidate="email" ControlToCompare="email2" Type="String"
EnableClientScript="false" Text="The email addresses must match!" 
runat="server" />
```

Optionally, you can wrap them all neatly in a [ValidationSummary](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_validationsummary.asp) control.

Finally, check Page.IsValid in your codebehind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["submit"] != null && Page.IsValid) 
    {
        register1();
    }
}
```

You can read about the other validation controls [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp).

Finally, fix your SQL so it's not vulnerable to SQL Injection:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [userinfo] ([username], [password], [email]) VALUES (N'" + Request.Form["username"].Replace("'","''") + "', N'" + Request.Form["password"].Replace("'","''") + "', N'" + Request.Form["email"].Replace("'","''") + "')";
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my current inputs, do I have to use asp inputs instead?

Comment: When trying to use your code to fix the SQL injection I'm getting an error saying the replace() function does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Asp.net server validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Validation Summary Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

By using this control you can be sure that all rules will be followed. You can check it server side by using

```
if(page.IsValid)
{
  //Code goes here

}
```